# How to merge two updates in Theano?

Tags: theano

For example, I have the cost function to be minimized: `J = J1 + a*J2`. To compute J1, I use `theano.scan` which returns an update object (let's call it `update1`) specifying update rule for shared variables involved in the scan function. Then I use `T.grad` to compute gradients of `J1`. Similarly, I use `theano.scan` to compute `J2` which returns another update object (let's call it `update2`). My question is how to merge these two updates into a single update so that I can use that single update rule to implement gradient descent?

Thank you.

p/s: If the question is not clear, I will try to add more details.

Comment: Did you solve the problem yet? I am having the same one.

Comment: Yes, I just added an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer for those who are still interested in the problem.

```
updates = update1
for var in update2:
    updates[var] = update2[var]
```